# Can a matrix be similar to more than one matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a little query about similar matrices I've been struggling with.

Suppose I have a 5x5 diagonal matrix A with 5 distinct eigenvalues as entries in the main diagonal. The question is, to how many diagonal matrices is A similar to?

My suggestion is that A can be similar to 5! matrices ( we can arrange the 5 eigenvectors in 5! ways) generating different invertible matrices P for each permutation)
 Another way of looking at it is that A is similar to only a matrix( itself) up to rearrangement of the eigenvalues.

so basically, does the order in which we input the eigenvectors in the invertible matrix P matter? 
any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The answer to the question as you've asked it is potentially infinitely many.  For example, every matrix of the form 
$$
\pmatrix{1&t\\0&2}
$$
with $t \in \Bbb R$ is similar to the diagonal matrix
$$
\pmatrix{1&0\\0&2}
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, why not post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @Spencer because given the phrasing of the question, it is not clear that this is the kind of answer that the asker is looking for.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, fair enough. Good answer btw, nice and simple.

Comment: @Spencer thanks.  I guess I'll put it in as an answer if there are no changes for a few hours

Comment: I'm really sorry for the delay in reply. The question is in fact how many diagonal matrices is A similar to? I've corrected the question. I'm sorry about that.

Comment: So what role does the matrix $P$ play?  I don't understand why we'd want a $P$ if the matrix is diagonal.